# Interior of subset in product topology = product of each subset in own topology

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ and $Y$ be two topological spaces. For $A \subset X, B \subset Y$, we consider $A \times B$ as a subset of $X \times Y$. Show that:

$\text{Int}(A \times B) = \text{Int}(A) \times \text{Int}(B)$

I think I can show it this way, but it seams a little easy:

Let $(x,y) \in \text{Int}(A \times B)$. We have an open $U \subset A \times B$ such that $(x,y) \in U$. So we have opens $V \subset X$, $W \subset Y$ such that $x \in V$ and $y \in W$ and $V \times W \subset U$. $V \subset A$, $W \subset B$ so $V \subset \text{Int}(A)$, $W \subset \text{Int}(B)$ so $x \in \text{Int}(A)$, $y \in \text{Int}(B)$. Now we have $(x, y) \in \text{Int}(A) \times \text{Int}(B)$ so $\text{Int}(A \times B) \subset \text{Int}(A) \times \text{Int}(B)$.

Let $(x, y) \in \text{Int}(A) \times \text{Int}(B)$ then there exists open $U \subset A$, $V \subset B$ such that $x \in U$, $y \in V$ so $(x, y) \in U \times V$. Obviously $U \times V$ is an open in $X \times Y$, contained in $A \times B$. This means $(x,y) \in \text{Int}(A \times B)$ so $\text{Int}(A) \times \text{Int}(B) \subset  \text{Int}(A \times B)$.

Both sets contain eachother so they are equal.

Comment: Please check the fact you are trying to show. You say you want to prove $int(A\times X) = int(A)\times int(B)$

Comment: Your edit made the answer you got meaningless.

Answer (score 0):

You claim:

We have opens $U \subset X$, $V \subset Y$ such that $x \in U$ and $y \in V$ and $U \times V \subset A \times B$

That is not where you should start from, you only know you have an open subset $U$ of $A\times B$ of which $(x,y)$ is an element. You have no reason to assume that $U$ is a rectangle (i.e. $U=V\times W$ for some $V\subseteq X$ and $W\subseteq Y$

Comment: Yes, I should have said that first. But doesn't it follow from that by the definition of the product topology?

Comment: It follows if you are able to prove it. If you are, do so.